# php - output buffering ob_get_contents not returning anything

Tags: php, output-buffering

I am trying to generate a static HTML from php however, i cannot get anything to output to $page, any ideas? cheers

```
ob_start();
$pageident = $tempdbid;   
include 'newpagegenerator.php';
$page  = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output it using an `echo` statement.

```
ob_start();
$pageident = $tempdbid;   
include 'newpagegenerator.php';
$page  = ob_get_contents();
echo $page;//<----- echo here
ob_end_clean();
```